# Windows Firewall Blocks GPMC

Tags: group-policy, windows-firewall

Found out that my Server 2008 R2 machine is not running firewall as it should. When I enable the firewall and try to open GPMC it states that it is unable to access the GPMC or the Primary Domain Controller. I am doing all of this on the Primary Domain Controller. How is the DC unable to see itself if it is behind its own firewall? And also since I can't access the GPMC I can't allow firewall rules. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** Firewall enabled and opened GPMC. It says unable to find server so I pointed it at the backup DC. GPMC opened but when I opened the Advanced Firewall Rules it gives me the following error:

> "There was an error opening the Windows Firewall with Advanced
>   Security snap-in.  The specified computer could not be remotely
>   managed.  Ensure that you are not trying to connecto a remote computer
>   with an earlier version of Windows.  Also, ensure that the Windows
>   Firewall rule for firewall remote mangement is enabled on the reomte
>   computer and that both the IPsec Serivce and the Windows Firewall
>   service on the remote computer are running.  Error code: 0x6D9"

At this point it seems to be a catch 22. Firewall off but can't edit Advanced Firewall rules on GPMC but with Firewall on can't access Advanced Firewall rules at all.

**EDIT 2:** Answering questions posed.

1. Can you work on the GPMC through an RDP session on the server so
   that you're editing things locally (not to be confused with editing
   the local group policies)? ***I cannot access the DC remotely as it closes all connections with firewall on. When I saw that issue happen I went to the DC locally and worked on it from there to find all this information.***
2. Can you verify your NIC settings (is the DNS set to localhost or local lan IP)? ***DNS is set to the local computer which is the DC as this is the requirement of the system.***
3. Do you have multiple DCs or just the one? ***Main DC and a backup DC.***
4. If you have multiple, can you duplicate the issue on another DC? ***I will try that on the backup DC and see if it does the same thing.***

**EDIT 3:** Findings
Enabled firewall on the BDC and it is working so it seems the only problem is the DC. Not sure why it is doing that to itself but everything is still working and the firewall is off only on the DC. So I went on to BDC and changed the GPO settings while adding the Firewall rules and then applied. Everything seems fine so far but will verify a little more tomorrow.

Comment: Have you ruled out a DNS issue?

Comment: @CIA Yes seems when you enable the Firewall on the DC it knocks out call communication. Updated the question.

Comment: Can you work on the GPMC through an RDP session on the server so that you're editing things locally (not to be confused with editing the local group policies)?  Can you verify your NIC settings (is the DNS set to localhost or local lan IP)? Do you have multiple DCs or just the one? If you have multiple, can you duplicate the issue on another DC?

Comment: @CIA updated question.

Comment: Sounds like a dns issue to me

Comment: @Richie086 Found that the firewall is only disabled on DC and not BDC. Seems to still be working somehow. Not sure how.